# Java List<Interface> = new ArrayList<Class>() results in error

Tags: java, list, arraylist, interface, implementation

I have an `interface`:

```
public interface Table {
Long getId();
}
```

And a `Class` implementing it:

```
public class EquipmentTable implements Table {

    private Long id;
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
private List<Table> data = new ArrayList<EquipmentTable>();
```

Getting the following error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList<EquipmentTable> to List<Table>
```

Comment: how about another class `AnotherTable` implements `Table`? then your list will break the paradigm.
You only want EquipmentTable then make List<EquipmentTable>

Comment: Btw, Java 7 Alleviates this by using diamond inference `new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: well how one class can implements another clss??